# updating textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, textbox

I have an input tag having some text in it. Now I would like that onclick of a button the text will be changed.

For some reason it is not being changed.

This is the input tag:

```
 <input id="network_table" type="text" value="oldValue" runat="server"/>
```

the following is the way I am trying to change the value of the input tag:

```
network_table.Value = "newValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

network_table.Text = "newValue";

Answer (score 0):

Bind the "onclick" event and apply this these methods:

In jQuery :

```
$('#network_table').val("your val");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Val

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('network_table').value = "your val";
```

you can do it serverside with "OnClick" event on button, assuming your controls are defined with `runat="server"` attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try and assign some meaningless class to the input and use that as a reference point to get in hold of the input field.

```
<input id="network_table" type="text" value="oldValue" runat="server" class="myInputField"/>

$('.myInputField').val('newValue');
```

Using the id will not work because you are using the 'runat=server' and it makes the id unavailable on client side and you would need to get the unique id first to be able to get in hold of it. This is a lot cleaner way but you need to make sure not to use the class elsewhere to avoid ambiguous results.

Here is a jsfiddle example which does what you want but on load.
http://jsfiddle.net/yX5ze/